# Get $_FILES temp name (of the binary file)

Tags: php, file, filenames, temp

i'm in trouble this is an example of `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpjCag18
```

i would like to get the temp binary filename so in this case `phpjCag18`

Is there anyway to get it from the `$_FILES[]`?

Ho to get it clean from path ?

Comment: basename() or explode() on slashes and use the last element of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
basename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

Comment: right , gonna accept your answer since returns exatcly what i need

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename) for this purpose.

```
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo basename( $tmp );
```

Or, if you're trying to get the extension, use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$extension =  strtolower( pathinfo($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) );
```

Comment: thanks just accepted the other's answer cause he was just faster :P thanks a lot for explanation +1